# How to remove a repetitive chain of a char in an string in python

Tags: python, regex

I have a string like `Hiiiiiiiiiiii` which it may be contains a chain of a char in it, here `i` which it is repeated more than one times.I want to replace this chain of `i`s with one `i` and get the `Hi` as the output.and for another example with the given word `eeeeeeemadeeefghddd` i want to get `emadefghd` as the output.How can I do this in python?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can replace every repetition of a character with the character itself using a fairly simple regex.

```
>>> import re
>>> re.sub(r'(.)\1+', r'\1', 'Hiiiiiiiiiiii')
'Hi'
>>> re.sub(r'(.)\1+', r'\1', 'eeeeeeemadeeefghddd')
'emadefghd'
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use `itertools` here

```
>>> import itertools
>>> s = "Hiiiiiiiiiiii"
>>> ''.join(i for i, _ in itertools.groupby(s))
'Hi'

>>> s = 'eeeeeeemadeeefghddd'
>>> ''.join(i for i, _ in itertools.groupby(s))
'emadefghd'
```

Comment: @TimPietzcker ah, right, this solution assumes that a sequence can appear no more than once for a given letter.

Comment: @TimPietzcker thanks for pointing out, how about itertools :)

Comment: Meh. It's not wrong, but it's not very elegant either. A regex is exactly the right tool for this job.

Comment: @timgeb updated my answer

Comment: ok, @TimPietzcker i will try this with regex thanks again, i am still in learning phase so i definitely need this kind of inputs, thanks for sharing

Answer (score 2):

You can loop through the `string` using `enumerate()` and check each character against the one before it, for example:

```
s = 'eeeeeeemadeeefghddd'
result = ''
for i, c in enumerate(s):
    if i == 0:
        result += c
    else:
        if c != s[i-1]:
            result += c
print result
```

Output:

```
emadefghd
```